# Getting 301 instead of 404 when adding trailing slash to URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404, trailing-slash

I've been working for hours in this and can't find information about it. Well yes, there is information, but I can only find separate solutions that don't work put toguether.

I'm trying to start from this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(php)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

The code works, I get the trailing slash. BUT if I put a non existing filename it returns a 301. For example:

```
http://www.example.com/thisfiledoesnotexist.php
```

The first header response is a 301, and it's logical, because it tries to return:

```
http://www.example.com/thisfiledoesnotexist.php/
```

And then it returns the 404, but this way it takes two requests to return a 404.

I supose that many people found this problem before, I believe it's a common issue, but I haven't found the solution to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the solution!!! It's not simple, and I don't really understand how it works. I tried  Adam Dimech's code, that can be found in [this page](http://code.adonline.id.au/hide-file-extensions-add-trailing-slash/).

The code is:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^/]+/)*[^.]+\.php(\?[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.php$ http://www.example.com/yourdirectory/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.example.com/yourdirectory/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

This code has to be put in each directory where we will be working with. If you use relative paths you have to use

The code worked fantastic. Now I can take off the php extension and force the trailing slash. Hope it's useful for more people!

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `-f` check. It checks whether the request is for an existing file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(php)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks Jon Lin, but it keeps adding the slash, so I get first a 301 and the 404 in the second request.